# Fetching Current User Profile using Objective C Google Plus Client Library

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am using the Google CLient Libraries for Objective C available here..
I have successfully been able to Authorize the user and get refresh token. (Using the GTMOAuthenticaion api embedded within).

In the Selector called after successful authorization I make the Get User Profile request as follows.. (I need the id of currently loggedin/authenticated user)

```
-(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Stop");
    } else {

        if ([auth canAuthorize]){
            [Mediator plusService].authorizer = auth;


            // Problematic Line
            GTLQueryPlus *profileQuery = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"]; // Notice the UserId Param


            profileQuery.completionBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    self.mediator.gProfile = object;
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"GPlus Service Error %@", error);
                }
            };

            [[Mediator plusService] executeQuery:profileQuery completionHandler:
            ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (error)
                    NSLog(@"Some Service Error %@", error);
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

If I put "me" as parameter, I get invalid user ID error string in jSON response.

However, If I provide some userId like my own 113632923069489732066 it works perfectly fine and returns the appropriate jSON response..!!

The Example for Google Plus inside Examples folder also fails to get current user profile ending with following error.

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid user ID: {0})" UserInfo=0x7a670fa0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Invalid user ID: {0}), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7a67b130: {message:"Invalid user ID: {0}" code:400 data:[2]}, error=Invalid user ID: {0}}
```

P.S. My API Console application doesn't work with iOS option under installed app but needs be configured with "Other" option. When configured with iOS option, the oAuth fails with invalid_client error response.

Comment: i am getting same problem . can you tell me how to handle gmail account which are not associated with gplus . . .

Comment: no idea.. If you are fetching GPlus info & there is not G+ account then obviously you can't. For google account profile, i think everything is now handled via G+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Mistake .. !! And a very silly one .. !!

I was signing in using a Gmail Account that was yet not associated with GPlus .. !! =/